# Inline math rendering limits underneath instead of besides the sum

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm here because I'm writing a thesis in LaTeX using overleaf and I'm having some troubles with the math inline style, which is not working.
This is what I'm writing:

```
$p_{nj}^2=\sum\limits_{i\in j}{\left|c_{in}\right|^2}$
```

and this is what I'm getting:

[image]

I know that using the inline math with `$...$` the sum should have the limits on its right rather than right over and below it. How could I obtain this effect?

Comment: This question would be better asked at [tex.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\limits`, you explicitly place them underneath. If you use `\sum_{...}` you get them, depending on the displaystyle, either besides or underneath:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$p_{nj}^2=\sum_{i\in j}{\left|c_{in}\right|^2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it even seems to me trivial... Again, thank you.